# ¿Se puede cambiar de pantalla desde un AlertDialog?

Tags: flutter, alertdialog

Quiero ver si existe la posibilidad de cambiar de pantalla utilizando la acción de un boton del `AlertDialog`.

código de `introducir el código aquí`

```
AlertDialog(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0)),
    title: Text(title),
    content: Column(
    //por default esta abarcando el maximo, para evitar eso se cambia para
    // que solo tome el minimo
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: <Widget>[
        Text(contenido),
        FlutterLogo(
        size: 100.0,
        )
    ],
    ),
    actions: <Widget>[
    FlatButton(
        child: Text('Cancelar'),
        //permite salir del Alert
        onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
            // Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/Inicio');
        }),
    FlatButton(
        child: Text('Reintentar'),
        //permite salir del Alert
        onPressed: () async {
            if (await _validaInternet()) {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
            }
        }),
    ],
);
```

Intente colocando las siguiente lineas

```
Navigator.of(context).pop();
Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/Inicio');
```

pero con el

```
Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/Inicio');
```

me da el siguiente error

```
I/flutter (15930): The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
I/flutter (15930): Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/Inicio", null) in the _WidgetsAppState.
I/flutter (15930): Generators for routes are searched for in the following order:
I/flutter (15930):  1. For the "/" route, the "home" property, if non-null, is used.
I/flutter (15930):  2. Otherwise, the "routes" table is used, if it has an entry for the route.
I/flutter (15930):  3. Otherwise, onGenerateRoute is called. It should return a non-null value for any valid route not
I/flutter (15930): handled by "home" and "routes".
I/flutter (15930):  4. Finally if all else fails onUnknownRoute is called.
I/flutter (15930): Unfortunately, onUnknownRoute was not set.
```

el **build** del main donde se asignan las rutas

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider(
      auth: auth,
      child: MaterialApp(
        routes: getApplicationRoutes(),
        home: result,
        theme: ThemeData(
            primaryColor: Colors.blue,
            // accentColor: Colors.purple,
            fontFamily: 'Lato'),
      ),
    );
  }


Map<String, WidgetBuilder> getApplicationRoutes() {
  final inicio = Inicio();

  return <String, WidgetBuilder>{
    "/Inicio"           : (BuildContext context) => inicio,
  };
}
```

Comment: puedes intentar lo que hicieron en SO en ingles [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51174654/flutter-dialog-start-new-activity)

Comment: @Artudoxo La respuesta que le dan es use algo similar a lo que ya hice `Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/Inicio');` y que me regresa el error que muestro.

Comment: Tienes las rutas bien definidas? puedes agregar el codigo de main.dart?

Comment: @diegoveloper ya agrege donde están las rutas quite las demás para evitar colocar mucho código

Comment: si le quitas esto :  Navigator.of(context).pop(); , y solo dejas el Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/Inicio'); , que sucede?

Comment: @diegoveloper ya lo intente y me sale el mismo error.

Comment: hmmm me parece extraño, si tienes el repo para revisar eso te podría ayudar

Comment: Ya te agregue como colaborador, el error esta en el archivo **Inicio_sesion_page.dart**  para llegar a replicar el error solo con dar en boton **Iniciar sesión** y en `AlertDialog` dar en **Cancelar**..

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97226/discussion-between-diegoveloper-and-richard).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisando tu código vi que el problema viene debido a que estás creando 2 widgets de `MaterialApp` y además estás generando las rutas en el segundo widget.

Elimina el segundo widget de material app, por lo que tu método `main` quedaría así :

```
void main() {
  final auth = Auth();
  runApp(Provider(
      auth: auth,
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: MyApp(),
        routes: getApplicationRoutes(),
        theme: ThemeData(
            primaryColor: Colors.blue,
            fontFamily: 'Lato'),
      )));
}
```

Y el widget `aplicacion` solo con esto :

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    prueba();
    print("APLICACION...");
    return result;
  }
```